# how to Implement Array.ConvertAll Method in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i can not Convert the T TYPE array in to Int array My Code is below .

T [] arra  = new T[arr.Length];

```
        int [] converted  = new int[arr.Length];
        T element;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length - 1-i; j++)
            {
                Type s = (Type)System.Int64; 
                Type t = arr.GetType();
                Converter<T,int> a;
                if (t.Equals(s))
                {
                    Array.ConvertAll<T, int>(arr, Converter < T,int> converted);
                }

                if (arr[j] >  arr[j + 1])
                {               

                    element = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = element;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an Exception? Are you getting a compile error?

Comment: @ Dede i am getting an error on "Convert<T,int>converted" that invalid expression term int

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: Because that is not valid code.

Comment: @Leppie Can you explain more !

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: The code is nonsensical. I have no idea what you are trying to do. Your code is full of errors. (1) `Type s = (Type)System.Int64;` wont compile (2) `Converter<T,int> a;` useless variable; besides the one you are complaining about.

Answer (score 2):

I am not **at all** clear (from the code) what you are trying to do, but to give a classic example of `Array.ConvertAll` (for comparison):

```
string[] data = { "123", "456", "789" };
int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(data, int.Parse);
```

Here, an `int[]` of length 3 is allocated, then (for each string) `int.Parse` is used to transform from a string to an int; the output should be the `int[]` with values `123`,`456`,`789`.

A more complex example (using lambda syntax):

```
string[] data = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
string[] reversed = Array.ConvertAll(data, s => {
    char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(chars); // note; not fully i18n safe
    return new string(chars);
});
```

Here the lambda body (which is our converter) reverses each string (by reversing the characters); the result should be the `string[]` with values `"cba"`,`"fed"`,`"ihg"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Array a = new Array();
    a.Cast<long>().ToArray();
```